# int object is not iterableの原因と発生機序が分かりません

Tags: python, python3

入力された文字列の中で、各アルファベットが計何回使われているか調べるコードなのですが

```
sen = str(input())
sen_lower = sen.lower()
alpha = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
alpha_num = [[0] for l in range(len(alpha))]
print(alpha_num)
for i in range(len(alpha)):
  for k in range(len(sen_lower)):
    if sen_lower[k] == alpha[i]:
      alpha_num[i] += 1
print(alpha_num)
```

以上のコードをもって、どのアルファベットがどれだけ使われているかを一覧にしたlistをprintしようとすると、

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-7e22160a987a> in <module>()
      7   for k in range(len(sen_lower)):
      8     if sen_lower[k] == alpha[i]:
----> 9       alpha_num[i] += 1
     10 print(alpha_num)
     11 

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

とエラーが出てしまいます。
これに関して、どなたかご説明をして頂けると幸いです。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alpha_num`の定義は「リストのリスト」になっています。（このことは直後の`print`による表示からもわかると思います）

結果として、9行目のコードはリストに整数値を足すという意味になるため、そのようなエラーが出ます。

多分あなたがやりたかったのは次のように`alpha_num`を定義することではないでしょうか？

```
alpha_num = [0 for l in range(len(alpha))]
```